# No modules named 'encodings' if python 3 directory is moved after building from source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, windows-10

I have looked around for this and not found any good answers. I Just pulled python from git and built it on Windows 10.  The python.exe file works fine when in the build location but, if you copy or move the folder you built into you get the following error upon running python.exe:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system
>   codec LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find
>   encoding
>
> Current thread 0x000060c8 (most recent call first):
>    .\python Fatal Python error:
>   Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00004f50 (most recent call first):

This is strange cause if you run python from the build directory
`D:\Users\brazg\Documents\GitHub\cpython\PCbuild\amd64` it runs fine.
I would like to know why python.exe doesn't run if the `amd64` directory is moved out of `PCbuild`.

As a side note I cannot find any information for setting up the Python root folder after building from source.

Comment: I'm not building on Linux. I'm building on Windows with build.bat

Answer (score 0):

*This is an answer from the perspective of someone that hasn't built python from source before.*

To answer my own question, what needs to be done after moving the Python binaries to a different location out of the `cpython\PCbuild` is you need to copy the `Lib` directory from the pulled sources because the `encodings` directory is in `cpython\Lib`.

Even though you the build is in `cpython\PCbuild\<build directory>` it still reads from `cpython\Lib` which makes sense but, I think should be made more clear in the official python documentation.

If you copy the `amd64` directory to a new location you need to copy the `cpython\Lib` directory into the `amd64` directory.  You can also delete all the `.exp, .lib and .pdb` files that were built with python from running `build.bat`. As they are all the compiler's linker and debug information.

I wish it was made more clear that `cpython\PCbuild\<build directory>` read up to `cpython\Lib` when run.